# How can i link two NodeJS servers under one domain?

Tags: node.js, server, dns, subdomain

for example i have a website that hosts a messenger app, it's written using Node JS on the back-end and has a server running on an obscure port (port 3455)

Currently my domain is being used to host my portfolio under a different port. the domain would be:

```
mydomain.com/
```

Is there anyway i could make it so that the app using port 3455 connects when i visit:

```
mydomain.com/messengerapp
```

even better would i be able to create a subdomain so its:

```
messenger.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by 301 redirection code. If you have apache server, add redirection rule to  .htaccess and if you have nginx server, add redirection rule to its config file.

Comment: im using a basic https server from nodejs, will i have to use one of those to get this working you think?

Comment: Actually this is not the usual process. Usually you need to request to node.js from client side app and client side can run directly on example.com/, the request could be on example.com:3455/ and this part would not be accessible by client